# power series of the reciprocal... does a recursive formula exist for the coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-series

Let $f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } b_nx^n$ and $\frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } d_nx^n$. Then the coefficients of the reciprocal of $f(x)$ can be written down. The first few terms are:

$d_0 = \frac{1}{b_0}$,

$d_1 = -\frac{b_1}{b_0^2}$,

$d_2 = \frac{b_1^2-b_0 b_2}{b_0^3}$

$d_3 = -\frac{b_1^3-2 b_0 b_1 b_2+b_0^2 b_3}{b_0^4}$

...

I was wondering if there is a general recursive (preferably not of course) formula for the coefficients of the reciprocal. If an arbitrary $n$ is given, can I write down a formula for $d_n$ (recursive or not)?

Regards

//edit: as the comments below suggest I think people are misinterpretating the question. I am not looking for someone to show me how to solve a system of linear equations by substitution... I want a formula for d_n,  Since posting the question,  I found such a formula for $d_n$ at http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/7/, see the section on Ratios of the direct function ... if anyone knows of how this formula is derived or any other references to it or similar formulas please let me know... thanks

Comment: There's no $a_n$ in your functions, only $b_n$. And this really, really does look like homework, and is not research level.

But anyway, before this gets closed: just use $f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{f(x)} = 1 + 0 \cdot x + 0 \cdot x^2 + \ldots$ and the formulae for multiplication of power series.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division

Comment: A homework question?? I dont think you read the question properly, or I lack your higher intellect. its one thing to solve a system on equations its quite another to write down a formula for the solution of the nth variable, n being arbitrary. 

I found the solution at http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/7/ ... I wonder how it was derived... Possibly somebody smart expanded enough terms found a pattern and used induction. That pattern is quite encryptic though. Any refs found would be appreciated.  

Comment: aukm, I agree: finding an *explicit closed form* formula for $d_n$ is not easy. However, by the method I outlined above, knowing the values of $d_0, d_1, 
\ldots, d_n$ (and the $b_j$), you can easily find $d_{n+1}$. Then you could easily programme a computer to calculate as many $d_j$ as you wish. As I understand it, that falls under the category of "recursive" formulae for $d_n$, which you say is allowed.

But then you refer to a website listing explicit formulae. So that answers your question, doesn't it? If you want a *proof* or *derivation* instead, you should say this in your question!

Comment: Zen, $d_n+1$ is found recursively by a computer but I am looking for a recursive or non recursive expression for $d_n+1$. A computer wont do this for me. I dont know how to make this any clearer. The formula in the link does answer my question, however, I would like to know how it was derived, who derived it ... basically where it came from. Note that it is a recursive formula. As far as I know a non recursive formula simply just doesn't exist.    

Comment: This is a straightforward application of Faa di Bruno (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula).  Voting to close.

Comment: Yuan, how can you close this question on the basis that its a staightforward application of the Faa di Bruno equation ... since 1) this equation is not known by many (read the third line of this paper, http://www.romanpress.com/MathArticles/FaaDiBruno.pdf). 
and 2) Even if the Faa di Bruno equation does provide an answer, its equivalence to the answer posted at http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/7/ is far from trivial ... and finally before you stupidly voted to close this question look at the responses below. The problem may not be hard but certainly not trivial!!

Comment: And Willie Wong!! the reference you pointed me to simply suggests you didnt even read or understand the question ... so you foolishly closing the question has annoyed because I was having a good discussion about the solution with other members.  

Comment: Actually I don't see the need of closing this question, for these reasons: (1) even a simple question may be of interest to other professional mathematicians not in that very field; and (2) sometimes simple or naive questions here gave rise to wonderful answer by our best users. That said, I would recommend aukm not to feel offended, and to avoid quarreling --for some reasons it's considerd umpolite. 

Comment: Related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238186/relating-face-polytopes-of-permutohedra-to-integer-partitions?lq=1

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A263633, http://oeis.org/A133314, and http://oeis.org/A049019

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors"? NO, this question helped me a lot.

Comment: This question has answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264615/inverse-rule-for-formal-power-series and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710252/multiplicative-inverse-of-a-power-series and here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53384/power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic .

Comment: Wow, this question helped me, how come it's too localized, very very weird!, If it should be closed, change the reason at least!

Comment: The best answers are posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262414/945479 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262417/945479.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assume $b_0=1$ to simplify things. You want a closed formula for the recursively defined sequence $$d_0=1$$ $$d_n=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}d_kb_{n-k}.  $$
Let $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)\in \mathbb{N}_ +^\omega$ be a multi-index with length $l(\alpha):=r$ and weight $|\alpha|:=\sum_{j=1}^r\alpha_j$. Let's denote $b_\alpha:=b_{\alpha_1}\dots b_{\alpha_r}$.

We have (induction)
$$d_n:=\sum_{|\alpha|=n}(-1)^{l(\alpha)}b_\alpha.   $$

There are of course several equal terms in the sum, due to the commutativity; summing equal terms, a corresponding smaller set of indices would be the increasing multi-indices (the number of terms in the sum would then be the number of partitions $p(n)$).

Comment: Or you can derive it just expanding the formal series $(1+y)^{-1}$ with $y:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k x^k$, and reordering.

Comment: Impressive, and ofcourse for $b_0 \neq 0$ the recursive relationship would be

$d_n=\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{b_0} & n=0 \\
 -\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{d_k}{b_0}b_{n-k} & n\geq  1
\end{cases}$

Can you point me to any references. I am not familiar with multi indices, but will look into them to see how this recursive relation is solved. Also by any chance have you got any good references to solution techniques (like this one) to recurrence relations. This is a type of math I have never learnt, but it is catching my interest more and more. 



Comment: While far from being related to the actual problem, the discussion reminds me the following:

(a) `exact` formula
$$
det(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \epsilon({\sigma}) {a_{1}}^{\sigma(1)} \cdots {a_{n}}^{\sigma(n)}
$$
compared with

(b) `recursive` formula: expansion by the first line of the determinant.

Difficult to say if (a) or (b) can give a `closed formula`  for say the determinant of a Hilbert matrix.

Comment: @aukm. Well, usually one treates recursive equations for sequences translating them into equations for the generating functions, because power series have a rich algebraic and analytic structure. For these techiques, you may like (some chapters of) Knuth's *Concrete mathematics*, or Wilf's *Generating functionology*. More advanced books, *Enumerative Combinatorics* by Stanley, and *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet.

Comment: @Pietro Majer I am curious about the Big-0 running time of your generating functions which I encountered in a Rutgers mathematics for computer science  course. How can it be improved to nearly linear running time? Would Hansel Lifting help for this purpose? Thank you

Comment: @Pietro Majer, Your generating formula for d subscript n has a closed form analytical solution rather than a recurrence relation making it parallelizable across n cores of a current many core CPU or GPU. Please confirm whether I am right or wrong.

Comment: Indeed one could possibly compute the $b_\alpha$ independently. I am not  an expert of computer science however, so consider posting a new question.

Comment: @Pietro Majer, Thank you for your assertion that the b subscript n can be computed independently. Your comment is supported by the following URL which I just read, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238186/relating-face-polytopes-of-permutohedra-to-integer-partitions?lq=1,

Comment: @Pietro Majer, Could we write a paper together on the idea of pararallelizing the polynomial division of Fourier spectra? Thank you.

Comment: (Incidentally, (7 years later) I see I forgot one author in a reference I gave above: *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet **and** Sedgewick. My inexcusable excuses!)

Answer (score 24):

Without loss of generality we can take $b_0$ to be 1, since 
\begin{equation*}\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n = b_0\biggl( 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (b_n/b_0)x^n\biggr).
\end{equation*}
Then for $b_0=1$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac1{f(x)} = \biggl( 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n\biggr)^{-1}\\
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty  (-1)^m\biggl( \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n\biggr)^m.
\end{equation*}
Expanding by the multinomial theorem and extracting the coefficient of $x^n$ gives 
\begin{equation*}
\frac1{f(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \kern 3pt  x^n \kern -5pt
\sum_{m_1+2m_2+3m_3+\cdots = n} (-1)^{m_1+m_2+\cdots} \binom{m_1+m_2+\cdots}{m_1, m_2, \ldots} b_1^{m_1}
b_2^{m_2}\cdots.\end{equation*}

Comment: Cheers, again if you could provide a reference I would be grateful...

Comment: If we generalize to
$f(x)^r$
then the coefficients in the expansion are called potential polynomials (though they're expressed in terms of exponential generating functions, so the formula will have some additional factorials.) A formula for potential polynomials, which generalizes this formula, can be found in Comtet's Advanced Combinatorics, section 3.5. These polynomials are closely related to Bell polynomials. Another reference is Weiping Wang and  Tianming  Wang, General identities on Bell polynomials. Comput. Math. Appl. 58 (2009), no. 1, 104–118.

Comment: @IraGessel, I am curious about the Big-0 running time of potential polynomials . How can it be improved  to nearly linear running time? Would Hansel Lifting help for this purpose? Thank you.

Comment: @Ira Gessel, I am curious about the Big-0 running time of potential polynomials . How can it be improved to nearly linear running time? Would Hansel Lifting help for this purpose? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: I don't know.

Comment: The best answers are posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262414/945479 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262417/945479.