# General term formula for sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_n,\cdots$ be a sequence of known positive numbers. Define 
$$
a_1:=k_1,\\
a_2:=C_2^2k_2+C_2^1k_1a_1,\\
a_3:=C_3^3k_3+C_3^2k_2a_1+C_3^1k_1a_2,\\
a_4:=C_4^4k_4+C_4^3k_3a_1+C_4^2k_2a_2+C_4^1k_1a_3,\\
\cdots\\
a_n:=C_n^nk_n+C_n^{n-1}k_{n-1}a_1+C_n^{n-2}k_{n-2}a_2+\cdots+C_n^1k_1a_{n-1}.
$$
What is the general term formula for $a_n$?

Comment: Let $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n/n!$, where $a_0=1$, and let $K(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty k_n x^n/n!$. Then $A(x) = 1/(1-K(x))$.

Comment: Could you please provide more details? I still can not get the general formula for $a_n$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Expand $1/(1-K(x))= \sum_n K(x)^n$ by the multinomial theorem. See my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53384/power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic/53407#53407.

Comment: Thanks very much!